# Only allow backbone access to my API?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, api, backbone.js

I have an API I am consuming for my web app that is external to my site. The ToS of the API I am consuming explicitly says I cannot make this data available to my users in an manner that they can generate a feed off my data.

I want to use backbone for my web app. However, using backbone with rails requires I generate json responses from the controller to backbone. I understand this is necessary, but I want this to be secure.

I've read many of the topics on here about securing a backbone implementation but I can't find any that address my specific problem. I have users that are not required to log in to use my site. These users can see the data I am providing. If I use backbone, this means they can perform the same request to my controller that backbone is doing and have an API available for them to write bots to use.

Is there any way I can prevent a user from looking at my javascript, seeing the calls I'm making, and write a bot? That is, can I insure that only my backbone javascript can talk to my controller and no one else can get a JSONified response?

Answer (score 0):

In short, no: by definition all JavaScript has to be run on the client's computer, which means there is nothing you can do to prevent the user from accessing that JS (if you could, they wouldn't be able to run your site).

You *can* "munge" your code using a tool like Uglify or the Google Closure compiler.  These tools replace variable names (eg. `var SECRET_KEY = 12345`) with shorter, non-meaningful ones (eg. `var AB = 12345`), and do other things that can make it difficult for someone to understand your code.

However, these tools will only make it difficult to find your secret key (eg. `12345`); the key (and all the rest of your application's data) will still be there in the source.

If you truly need to hide some data from the user, you have to keep that data on the server (which would mean that you'd have to always consume that API indirectly, but talking to your server and having your server talk to it).